# Get channels using YouTube API

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to get all the channel details under my YouTube account using YouTube API v3 in Android. Here is the code for the same.

```
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory,
                        credential).setApplicationName(Constants.APP_NAME)
                        .build();
ChannelListResponse clr = youtube.channels()
                            .list("contentDetails").setMine(true).execute();

Log.d("","Channel count = "+clr.getItems().size());
```

Currently, I have configured 2 channels under my account. But the above line always prints the channel count as 1.

Any idea on how to get all channel details using API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am facing the same issue , i have created 2 channels but i am getting only one

Comment: There is a tracked Google bug for this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203851452

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, which is got from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java

```
// Construct a request to retrieve the current user's channel ID.
        // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
        YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list("contentDetails");
        channelRequest.setMine(true);

        // In the API response, only include channel information needed
        // for this use case.
        channelRequest.setFields("items/contentDetails");
        ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute();

        List<Channel> channelsList = channelResult.getItems();
        if (channelsList != null) {
            // The user's default channel is the first item in the list.
            String channelId = channelsList.get(0).getId();

            //USE FOR LOOP HERE TO RETRIEVE ALL CHANNELS 
        }
```

Thanks. This may help you.

Comment: i am facing the same issue , i have created 2 channels but i am getting only one